# C++ suddenly blocks on reading a frame from IP camera using VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, frame, video-capture, ip-camera

I'm using OpenCV 3. Grabbing a frame using VideoCapture with an IP Camera is blocking if the camera goes disconnected from the network or there is an issue with a frame.
I first check if `videoCapture.isOpened()`. If it is, I tried these methods but nothing seems to work:

**1) grabber >> frame**

```
if(grabber.isOpened()) {
    grabber >> frame; 
    // DO SOMETHING WITH FRAME
}
```

**2) read**

```
if(grabber.isOpened()) {
    if(!grabber.grab()){
      cout << "failed to grab from camera" << endl;
    } else {
      if (grabber.retrieve(frame,0) ){
        // DO SOMETHING WITH FRAME
      } else {
        // SHOW ERROR
      }
    }
}
```

**3) grab/retrieve**

```
if(grabber.isOpened()) {
    if ( !grabber.read(frame) ) {
      cout << "Unable to retrieve frame from video stream." << endl;
    }
    else {
     // DO SOMETHING WITH FRAME
    } 
}
```

The video stream gets stuck at some point grabbing a frame with all of the previous options, each one blocks but doesn't exit or returns any error.

Do you know if there is a way to handle or solve this? Maybe some validations, try/catch or timer?

Comment: A very good example of using grab function can be found here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp Make sure you do the essential checks in every step. checking if video capture is open is good but not enough.

Comment: .read() is the same as .grab followed by .retrieve so your app is reading a frame and then tries to read a 2nd frame, which means to wait until a new frame is available (depending on fps it can need some time...)

Comment: @Micka I tried the three options separate, all of them keep blocking the program at some point...I think I need some sort of validation or waiting time.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Micka I added some example code

Comment: @Elmira Thanks for the suggestion. I check and I think im doing the same thing, do you think i'm missing anything from the example you showed me?

Answer (score 3):

this issue is solved by [this merge](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/6053) but unfortunetely opencv_ffmpeg.dll is not released yet.

you can find [here](https://github.com/alalek/opencv_3rdparty/tree/ffmpeg/master_20160207/ffmpeg) updated opencv_ffmpeg.dll and test.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will check it out. The thing is that I am on linux, any thoughts on that?

Comment: if you read comments [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/6053) you will see my comment asking how to update opencv_ffmpeg.dll for windows. you could ask there how about linux.

Comment: UPDATE: I asked and I was told "There is no separate opencv_ffmpeg.dll on Linux. To enable ffmpeg support in OpenCV you need to install ffmpeg development packages (-dev/-devel, depends on Linux distribution) and rerun OpenCV CMake"